# Some total noob questions on volume rendering

Tags: xtk

I have been asked to provide a 3D visualisation of data from a prototype of a new type of scanner.

The data will be provided to me as a cube of voxels. Each voxel will be a data structure who's exact contents are yet to be determined.

It *seems* like xtk might be a good base on which to tackle this problem, but as I'm a total noob in this area, I have some pretty fundamental questions...

1) I'm having trouble finding simple explanations of the various file formats that xtk supports - which (if any) represent cubes of voxels?

2) For those, do the file formats also specify the data structure for each voxel? How would you tackle rendering a file that had an arbitrary data structure? ( ie If, say, each voxel contained a numerical measurement of "foo" at that location - how would you go about getting xtk to render a vizualization)

Apologies for the noob questions - any pointers in the right direction would be very gratefully received.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is a list of supported file formats: https://github.com/xtk/X/wiki/X:Fileformats

the formats under "DICOM/Volume Files" are the ones you want. we support different data types for the voxels (sint, uint, float, double etc.).

XTK converts the numerical values of each voxel to grayscale and renders them.

Comment: Hi haehn,

Thanks so much for your answer :)

DICOM seems to be primarily for medical imaging - is there any reason it would not be suitable for other sorts of imaging do you think?

Also, if my voxels turn out to be a custom data structure rather than a simple value, is there a way I can plug in my own handler for it? Lastly, I presume I can map to colours rather than grayscale? I have seen some references to 'colour maps', are they what I need to look into?